# Microsoft Graph: Uploading files to shared with me folder on OneDrive?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I was able to successfully upload to Shared Documents folder using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40369180/microsoft-graph-uploading-files-to-shared-library-instead-of-users-library/48142043?noredirect=1#comment83262098_48142043) approach. But I am looking for a way to upload files to Shared WithMe folder on OneDrive.

Is it possible to upload to "/Shared WithMe" folder on OneDrive? If so, which is the right syntax for the PUT (small file) or POST (upload session)? I spent a lot of time to figure this out but no luck.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

I had success with this approach:

`PUT /drives/{driveid}/items/{itemid}/content`

I was able to retrieve the `driveid` and the `itemid` from the `DriveItem` entity.  For a given `DriveItem`, the `driveid` is at `DriveItem.RemoteItem.ParentReference.DriveId` ([ItemReference docs](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/itemReference)) and the `itemid` is at `DriveItem.RemoteItem.Id` ([RemoteItem docs](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/remoteItem)).

The Files.ReadWrite.All permission seems to be required.

This approach worked for me in the UWP C# Graph SDK.

Answer (score 0):

Complementing what [@Mark Scott](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52131097/2741235) answered:

First, I got the `driveId` and `itemId` from shared with me files URI response:

```yaml
GET /me/drive/sharedWithMe
```

To use the shared URI to upload a file, I need to change it for contains the file name and `:` upload URI characters. So, my URI is:

```yaml
PUT /drives/{driveid}/items/{itemid}:/FILE_NAME.EXTENSION:/content
```

With this is possible to upload a file to a folder that you know the `Id`. But you can go further! Also, it's possible to use the known folder `Id` as root and specify a path to upload your file. This is great because automatically create the folder in the path that you specify..`

```yaml
PUT /drives/{driveid}/items/{itemid}:/FOLDER/CHILD FOLDER/FILE_NAME.EXTENSION:/content
```

In the end, this will upload your file in: `KNOWN_FOLDER_ID_NAME/FOLDER/CHILD FOLDER/FILE_NAME.EXTENSION`

**Bonus tip:** You can get the shared folder `Id` from onedrive web URL when you are in the folder. The URL is like this:

```yaml
https://onedrive.live.com/?id=YOUR_FOLDER_ID&cid=DONT_USE_THIS
```