# How to use Microsoft API to upload file to folder shared across from a different domain?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I am able to use Microsoft API to upload file to folder shared within the same domain. For example, `user1@mycompany.com` share a directory to `user2@mycompany.com`, then I am able to write to the shared folder via `user2@mycompany.com`.

More specifically, I am able to create an upload session using following API:

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/<drive_id>/items/<dir_id>:/<filename>:/createUploadSession`

However, the same API would return `404` if the `drive_id` and `dir_id` is from user of another domain. For example, `another@othercompany.com` share folder to `user2@mycompany.com`, then upload file via `user2@mycompany.com`.

The error message from API is

```
{
    "error": {
    "code": "itemNotFound",
    "message": "The resource could not be found.",
    "innerError": {
        "request-id": "526d86bc-c620-4782-a74d-c8cd8284df8b",
        "date": "2018-10-19T20:54:37"
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any API that would work for OneDrive file upload to shared folder across different domains?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Microsoft Graph: Uploading files to shared with me folder on OneDrive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48142134/microsoft-graph-uploading-files-to-shared-with-me-folder-on-onedrive)

Comment: This is different than "shared with me"
 folder as I am interested in cross domain sharing. It also looks like that cross domain sharing requires no login, anyone who with the link from email received will able to upload via browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

at this point you can only access drives from the organization of the authenticated account. If `alice@company1.com` shares with `bob@company2.com` and `bob@company2.com` has a guest account in the `company1` organization, then I believe if you log into `company1` with the external guest account, then you'll be able to access the shared drive.

Alternatively, if your app is able to authenticate to both accounts, you might be able to take advantage of the fact that upload and download URLs are self-authenticating and do something like this:

1. using auth token for `alice@company1.com`, call createUploadSession on the folder.
2. using auth token for `bob@company2.com`, download file that is to be shared.
3. using upload url from #1, upload the file (no other auth token needed here)